Positioning icons relative to the position of an image using kotlin/android studio
I am trying to position some icons around a central image in specific locations. The effect I'm trying to achieve is like an oval with icons at certain spots around the border of the oval.
The way I thought to do it in my code is  by putting everything in a Box and using padding and offsets, but, this doesn't work with different screen sizes. Meaning, when I add padding it will adjust it based on the center of the screen but for smaller screen sizes the icons move a different distance.
Is there some way to make the icons align around the picture?
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.table),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.9f),
        )

        Icon1(Modifier.padding().offset(x = (90).dp, y = (-220).dp))
        Icon2(Modifier.padding(top = 18.dp))
        //Icon3,4 etc

    }


https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/constraintlayout

thanks, I ended up using constraintlayout to solve this. I searched the docs before posting this but I just didn't find it on my own. I think if I searched the term widget instead of image I would have found it. Thanks again

great! you could write also as an answer what worked for you :D

Use Modifier to position relatively.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {

    Image(
        align = Alignment.Center,
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.table),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.9f),
    )

    Icon1(Modifier.padding().offset(x = (90).dp, y = (-220).dp))
    Icon2(Modifier.padding(top = 18.dp))
    //Icon3,4 etc

}

